Emacs Font Size Change
I try to increase the font size in certain major modes (say M1) using
(add-hook ' (lambda () (text-scale-increase 2))) in init.el.
This works fine!
However, I also intend to preserve the existing font size while doing a revert-buffer
to which I use:
(defun save-text-scale ()
(setq prev-scale-size (buffer-local-value 'text-scale-mode-amount (current-buffer))))

(defun restore-text-scale()
(text-scale-increase prev-scale-size))

(add-hook 'before-revert-hook 'save-text-scale)
(add-hook 'after-revert-hook 'restore-text-scale)

This normally works fine as well in modes other than M1!
It leads to the problem of an increased size when I do a revert buffer
the mode M1 where the major mode size increase kicks in as well because of the mode hook.
Any idea how to get rid of this? My intention is to control the starting font size as well as
preserving it during a revert buffer.
Controlling & preserving font size in emacs.

you could store the increment (eg. 2) in a variable, my-text-scale-increment, and let bind it around revert-buffer

Thanks for the pointer.  Being new to emacs I am not very good in thinking of solutions. For the benefit of others I have now used a buffer local variable (global otherwise) for mode M1 where I set the local value accordingly. Then during revert buffer I just adjust the  difference using the local value to make up for the load buffer size increase.
